# root can't write or modify /bin, /usr/bin, /sbin, /usr/sbin

Tags: permissions, root

On a debian system, I'm logged in as root.

I cannot create any files in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`.

I *can* create files in `/`, `/usr`, `/usr/local`, `/usr/share`, etc, etc.

All these directories are owned by root and have permission 755.

The partition is not full.

```
touch /usr/bin/foo

touch: cannot touch `/usr/bin/foo': Permission denied
```

(and the file does not already exist)

```
touch /usr/local/foo
```

(no error)

Also, `chown` and `chmod` fail on directories named "`bin`" or "`sbin`", but not on other directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check the file attributes using `lsattr`. It's well possible that those directories have been made "immutable" to prevent alteration, even by root.

Comment: Some directories under /usr are marked "I" (not "i" for immutable). It turns out root can't write to any of the directories marked "I".

man chattr sez:
The "I" attribute is used by the htree code to indicate that  a  directory  is  being indexed using hashed trees.  It may not be set or reset using chattr(1), although it can be displayed by lsattr(1).

I have no idea what that means, or why directories would be stuck 
in this state, but you've set me off in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like those directories where you can't change anything were mounted read-only.

You might want to check the output of `mount`.

Comment: Not mounted read-only

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Manni's answer, often times a file system will be mounted read only if there was an error during a file system check.  You may want to check your boot logs to see if there were errors.